# Jquery element load effect on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project and I wanted to have a sort of fade effect on an element on my page, That if the page loads these elements comes in with a fade-in effect. I tried something very simple in jquery like `$("#showEffect").show(1000);` But that doesn't work. How can I add these effect to my element?

Comment: Try `toggle` on your element.

Comment: Or you could try jQuery’s $(‘#showEffect’).fadeIn(1000); (see http://api.jquery.com/fadein)

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet we might be able to give a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show element first you have to hide it.

```
$("#element").hide();
$("#element").show(1000);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: It does solve it! thanks! I need 10 more minutes until I can accept the answer

Comment: rather using hide with js to hide the element manually try adding a class with display:none property and then use `$('#element').removeClass('class-for-hindinng').show(interval');` to avoid unwanted effects..

Comment: One small thing though, When I add `$("#showEffect").toggle( "puff" );` the effect does not work. It just shows the standard sort of "fold" effect. How does this work?

Comment: With `.hide()` the element can still be seen quick before JavaScript jumps in. Could be a problem on slow devices or browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#element').fadeToogle(500);
```

you can also change the time limit by changing the milliseconds as I've put `500`

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `display: none` in CSS.

And show it with JavaScript

`$(this).fadeIn("fast");`

On slow devices it still would show the element for a short time, if you use `.hide()` instead, because JavaScript isn't fast. It relies on your device/browser's performances so better stick with `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to build on this and have a more complex animation at some point, `toggleClass` may be worth looking into; this will toggle a css class on the element so you could add something like a size change while fading:

```
$('#element').toggleClass('my-class');
```

A css class that would shrink and fade the element:

```
.my-class {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: 100ms all;
}
```

You would want to include `transition: 100ms all` on the css for `#element` as well so that the animation is smooth when the class is toggled off and the element fades back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any class or any custom css approach this is something you can try.

This example assume your element is **not in hidden state** so it will be hidden by js when page done loading and then fade in will bring it into picture.. :D
Hope it helps..

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#div1').toggle().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px"></div>
```